# submit data to webform

Tags: c++, qt

How I can submit string to webform, if I using QWebKit, c++?

```
<div style="text-align:center;"> 
<form id="postform" method="post" action="javascript://" onsubmit="chat.add();"> 
<div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 



<input type="button" onclick="chat.add();" class="chat_button" value="Send!" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [QNetworkAccessManager::post](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#post-2)